# How to finish an activity when a div is clicked in webview

Tags: java, android

I want to close an activity if a `<div class="close" id="closer">close</div>` is clicked

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a javascript interface to your WebView.

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyInterface");
```

Make sure you have enabled javascript:

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Now in your activity create a function annotated with @JavascriptInterface that will finish the activity.

```
@JavascriptInterface
pubic void closeActivity(){
 finish()
}
```

Now modify your HTML to call the above function:

```
<div class="close" id="closer" onclick="MyInterface.closeActivity()">close</div>
```